# Coding Error with Python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to code a game in python ( its a school assignment) and I want the game to have multiple screens, for example a title screen, an about screen, and the screen where you get to play the game. However, to keep things simple, I want all these screens to show up on the same window.

Currently, I've been defining commands that are running a specific screen, and telling python to run that command when the variables are correct (i.e. when the user has pressed the button to take them to the next screen). However, all I get is a blackscreen, and python immediately closes. The funny thing is that the log shows no sign of any problems, which is very strange.

If you could help me fix this code, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pygame
import random
name = 'Squash Ninja'
size = (700, 500)
rect_x = 50
rect_y = 50
rect_x1 = 345
rect_y1 = 397
rect_x_change = 10
rect_y_change = 10
rect_x_change1 = -10
rect_y_change1 = -10
vari = 0
#Colours#
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (18, 128, 13)
YELLOW = (234, 255, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 132, 0)
LGREEN = (0,255,0)
PURPLE = (204, 14, 166)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
#Starts Pygame#
pygame.init()
#Opens window#
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
#Running Variables#
done = False
title = True
about = False
#Screens#
def title():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type ==  pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                print('User pressed mouse.')
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                print("User pressed a key")
                pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE, [0,0], [100,100], 5)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                print("User let go of a key.")
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
    screen.fill(BLUE)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,[200,20,350,100],0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,[280,180,200,50],0) 
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,[280,240,200,50],0) 
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,[280,300,200,50],0) 
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 45, True, False)
    text = font.render("Squash Ninja", True, LGREEN)
    screen.blit(text, [255, 75])
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)    
    text = font.render("Play", True, YELLOW)
    screen.blit(text, [350, 200])    
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
    text = font.render("About", True, YELLOW)
    screen.blit(text, [340, 260])
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
    text = font.render("Quit", True, YELLOW)
    screen.blit(text, [355, 320]) 
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 10, True, False)
    text = font.render("Version 1.2", True,WHITE)
    screen.blit(text, [650, 470])
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 10, True, False)
    text = font.render("Created by Adrian Ngai", True,WHITE)
    screen.blit(text, [600, 480])     
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 10, True, False)
    text = font.render("Copyright 2014, all rights reserved.", True,WHITE)
    screen.blit(text, [555, 490])         
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos ()
    if 280 + 200 > mouse [0] > 280 and 180+50 > mouse[1] > 180:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,LGREEN,[280,180,200,50],0)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
        text = font.render("Play", True, RED)
        screen.blit(text, [350, 200])    
    if 280 + 200 > mouse [0] > 280 and 240+50 > mouse[1] > 240:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,LGREEN,[280,240,200,50],0)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
        text = font.render("About", True, RED)
        screen.blit(text, [340, 260])
        if event.type ==  pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:        
            title = False
            about = True
    if 280 + 200 > mouse [0] > 280 and 300+50 > mouse[1] > 300:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,LGREEN,[280,300,200,50],0)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
        text = font.render("Quit", True, RED)
        screen.blit(text, [355, 320])     
        if event.type ==  pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            done = True
    #bouncing rectangle#
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, LGREEN, [rect_x, rect_y, 50, 50])
    rect_x += rect_x_change
    rect_y += rect_y_change
    if rect_y > 450 or rect_y < 0:
        rect_y_change = rect_y_change * -1
    if rect_x > 650 or rect_x < 0:
        rect_x_change = rect_x_change * -1  
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, PURPLE, [rect_x1, rect_y1, 50, 50])
    rect_x1 += rect_x_change1
    rect_y1 += rect_y_change1   
    if rect_y1 > 450 or rect_y1 < 0:
        rect_y_change1 = rect_y_change1 * -1
    if rect_x1 > 650 or rect_x1 < 0:
        rect_x_change1 = rect_x_change1 * -1   
    for i in range(50):
        x = random.randrange(0, 800)
        y = random.randrange(0, 800)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE,[x,y],3)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)    
def about() :
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==  pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print('User pressed mouse.')
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print("User pressed a key")
        pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE, [0,0], [100,100], 5)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True    
    screen.fill(BLUE)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,[200,20,350,100],0)
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 45, True, False)
    text = font.render("About", True, LGREEN)
    screen.blit(text, [255, 75])    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,[280,300,200,50],0) 
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)     
    text = font.render("Back", True, YELLOW)
    screen.blit(text, [355, 320])  
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos ()    
    if 280 + 200 > mouse [0] > 280 and 300+50 > mouse[1] > 300:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,LGREEN,[280,300,200,50],0)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
        text = font.render("Back", True, RED)
        screen.blit(text, [355, 320])     
        if event.type ==  pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            title = True
            about = False
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)   
def done():
    while not done:
        print() 
    while done:
        pygame.quit()
#Game Loop#
while vari == 0:
    done()
while title:
    title()
while about:
    about()
#Closing Sequence#
print('Test fail :(')
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Did it work at some stage while you were writing it or did you write all that code without testing it along the way?

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem might be here

```
done = False
...
def done():
    while not done:
        print() 
    while done:
        pygame.quit()
```

Even though you have the variable "done" assigned earlier, you're reassigning it to a function. Because done is no longer false, the function executes the second loop ("while done:") and immediately quits.

To get the behavior you're expecting, you should rename the function done() to something like is_done(). i.e.

```
def is_done():
    while not done:
        print()
    while done:
        pygame.quit()
```